# How to distinguish between 2D and 3D objects according to depth

Tags: image-processing, 3d, 2d

I'm trying to distinguish by code between a real 3D object and its picture - a 2D object, based on depth information.

However the picture (= the 2D image) might be captured from noisy background, so I need something more sophisticated than just having  diversified depth information; also, the depth camera's output itself might be noisy and there isn't a straight-forward correlation between the model shape and the depth information.

Any advice - academical sources as implementation ideas - are very welcome.

Comment: So you want to detect the difference between a picture of a scene and a picture of that picture? If so, you don't stand a chance .... if not, perhaps you could explain a bit more with some examples?

Comment: @RogerRowland - Sorry for not being clear. For example: I have two pairs of color-depth images. One: color/depth pictures of a doll, second: color/depth pictures of a pictured doll. I want to create a flow that for pair no. 1 generates a "yes" output, and for pair no. 2 a "no" output. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I see, so in this case would the colour/depth pictures of the picture always be at some known orientation? E.g. if always normal to the viewing direction, then calculating the average spread in the depth map might be a good enough metric. If it's a known angle, this would be more difficult. Perhaps you could show some data.

Answer (score 1):

in that case it is easy ...

1. segmentate the image to mask only the object
2. obtain 3 points from image "evenly" dispersed along the object surface

   - if you have nonlinear depth information then you need to linearize it
   - Basically you need `x,y,z` in orthogonal coordinate system
3. compute the plane from these 3 points
4. pick few points along the grid or all points belonging the object

   - and check their "distance" from computed plane
   - if any of them is bigger then treshold then the object is not planar
   - that means it is not picture of object but the object itself
   - [image: example]

[Notes]

- if the image of object is projected on non-planar surface
- then this will not work
- you will need to find out the z-coordinate changes in masked area
- and if any bumps are found (1st or 2nd derivation) then it is probably an object...
- especially near object borders and background
- for safer matching you would need more information about lighting or object ...